# openpgp-php can't decrypt cipher text from other clients

Tags: php, gnupg, openpgp

See source code below to reproduce this issue. Step 1 encrypts the message using **gnupg** while step 2 decrypts the message from step 1 using **openpgp-php**. To execute code ensure you have PHP gnupg and openpgp-php installed. (see [singpolyma
/
openpgp-php](https://github.com/singpolyma/openpgp-php) ) for openpgp-php documentation.

**What I am trying to achieve**
I have a backend server and a mobile app which can only communicate through email. For simplicity assume that step 1 is the backend server and step 2 is the mobile client. Messages flow back and forth between server and client. The backend server should be able to encrypt a message meant for the mobile app which in return decrypts the message and sends an encrypted reply to the backend.

```
 <?php
    @include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/lib/openpgp.php';
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/lib/openpgp_crypt_rsa.php';
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/lib/openpgp_crypt_symmetric.php';
    
    
    /**
     * Note: Step 1 and step 2 represents a client-server setup
     * I know it's wrong to share private keys but this was generated specifically for this test
     */
    
    /**
     * step #1 (Encryption)
     * encrypt message meant for hamfri-2@example.com at step #2 
     */
    
    // public key for hamfri-2@example.com
    $public_key1 = "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
    
    mQENBF+xv34BCAD9ttzdbXx81yKIlWi0zqRgHVYc07M9ymoqCzoIIrmaCcvkARAJ
    I4IZ36PnXxnLdfMehMDjxeT6PAJDb71oMc85jA+h5c+ya4b+m9OwlGW/e7WgieBB
    WGt8NRnnKjwGbwDq7qd2aC2T/ZDBZQFF4wAJjoZop5Wh7NxK8QFV05ES6KXU/hJF
    wySbyoSYJb4A3VNrpoEF92vA22aUFn2RrktCXwaaMXoOyLuFDebxOrKgzI5EfhMa
    CRBxv4ufNfcAm1uEpqILngou/kxUs5QYW6VaSmV858+bpzcMGR73X1hHY9p0dHO1
    QTaIJU/8E91whaCxihDOsyO5jJG6DIhEbwJVABEBAAG0IFBST0ZJR0FURSA8aGFt
    ZnJpLTJAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20+iQFOBBMBCgA4FiEEFL28kQaiGEUK7cm+n15EvbMd
    HkgFAl+xv34CGy8FCwkIBwIGFQoJCAsCBBYCAwECHgECF4AACgkQn15EvbMdHkhF
    IggAsvxVIZOTo9SrNvEERUz05X8z7+CNR1m4rCL4Q5mtaFhL0RcsH2FpLqd7+96J
    txFBRL5XaUiDQeVc1qzSNnr062DtR0jxvR59Rg+aBfyX2haNHKbD3Dw6e2WaDXMe
    OkhJjS2h16Wc+4ztRerGQ0vI+fTaImrs43uCuzKrMPo39/hxewv5BXRpkXrSCZ/X
    9jTH+XQxBsEaXe+W9pW5tXpSSVUkccBwuKWJBygzI41PQ+Xi39tn+TxVk+kFDASV
    7uvYMPU3IBdbQ/F8xcnb6q6uH2r7lIZRUSsj/H3SHlcDwiBXZgez49Re9eZjFpvp
    7lUiXQeGMktj3MboVAHglOw6srkBDQRfsb9+AQgAxVvq+VApWsPaN7Wgj1uepVtu
    nJ8BiEZ2CNq6mM32rTfYrw3Ckv7lfKHNsTVo7Ek8bWbxR1I/DhBCvDDRijtEWkNF
    GO1EfQx+2mYJPsPiO9Y+HoL7L839FapXqrPLnhEczR3s8IkTZrggZ2ClZ2pI8cwS
    GysW4wxjExzoEiXyoF4XVZZWJgq2blkXP5avnZhmWyK88e0ZFmut1+dO/eJ3nFT9
    uxqBXZSlLVuo4GGVLz+Xa3ZuJKtACEyNQnJ4zYVrW/zLyVSThN5Um95QB2A0hup1
    f92oMs5jiUAk/PFPs3h6qOqIsTo5gyuXM/c39ZqGM474c2yY0ImpolXqZ85rNwAR
    AQABiQJsBBgBCgAgFiEEFL28kQaiGEUK7cm+n15EvbMdHkgFAl+xv34CGy4BQAkQ
    n15EvbMdHkjAdCAEGQEKAB0WIQR3zuJGs/Iyh6FlFq91FMPrcW4x3gUCX7G/fgAK
    CRB1FMPrcW4x3ozOB/45X6+t9JeUSBp1e1jfr+CJMAlf6HiSsQd7BpA1UFGU42oO
    BqFNpT7q7TwcUlbf9JHq8qL10SuPgIot04vDQSsaMxWc8X/E4OCDo9WhOT5CwmjJ
    LzmQwhWzpAlhw93sQTJY7oKyW3lasxyDjBhIDHz0lagNfU6S5ZkR8U5S2qoM6VRr
    bDVP224HXXjhLUvbChF+G5MvWaAOExPvz2Sc69jcQaQ5D4PM65qfatoJZEdQjREn
    YGU4c7ZqPPunQSbIlMzufFsu2mMM1/mLKMA12+VPoMbrzoMoJD4ENNsFjXmYjlDl
    wLrs1pYDu7bjm5Aqz1iylMrup+eiv5TqXFX93PR50+UH/A0gg6LkuBJOJ9G1TCN/
    G32NmB3/NOhLPZgdF9E36cxV6/EiOwYP2YVG4eBS+Sajk4PieYupNI91rwU5O9gR
    UCekv3TbI7F41oin/tF9++RoLpGyRjOT4P7PsBfg9PTIzHBlVmIBo88JP14IhRcN
    najX81Mw01esspl2+bkX1MgmZ7SPoODZ422BLYEt8qQrxLoOI6gUzz/NpY4OpoRS
    Qdx3TEmHKzLIIWZgkMC1IwNX4Jc4gLF8pMD4miSwm5RRlHzop7APmCs6F7jC+evo
    H3xWQTvkq7Rrh0ykvZOeX+kEvEfglFrFDM2GE0XVy+khDenC6BHgx2D6ZJIPOs18
    pko=
    =vTCt
    -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
    ";
    
    // private key for hamfri@example.com
    $private_key1 = "-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
    
    lQOXBF+xvukBCADfsgmVrgw95kpxL+yM0BRC4Z/UHRoOCj4N9lOyvhUoa9rs30/W
    Xd8RXddkF2pjPr2OjRRe+PbpKxkkxAe1qxmICaIh/Xp/gS6XHGdqgvX/PuQhw3+T
    eGSVdXLxSwRdlGW1AZeH3WWSmqviYEtkwxWoah6g4ubmd/b6wp3EtSw4YpA3l1+C
    J313MV1IbptjJkrLHy+JqAV4CA6ziCkOwERc5fvtNdmmvbXrMfb5ObN2F6RfYwZS
    yLSvJB7n4CDsvLwGbXRHP0we0+eXJLt902k0uTW27IZhHElatvnxXwjqA5mcVfIK
    W3ks3VHLx0PbjIhghAUg7Pg8HgPlPGVBS8mhABEBAAEAB/df5jO1t6gH4XKIk8MV
    mx8UjSW4CcHhwwJXegLn3hWz/okcg5/2hsfa6iAtCNzTL1KUimbxUEqKK6/b0y56
    858+cuLPL5wUjY0ru0GaqApOIugqkWVgE30Llg5w43g7piL0NnqABKpG74hAxIeN
    6xSd3uDCmIPkyglX95crfYA3qzwl5KC/Jnn5Vr9ZCdDk1aipCNQtdxKYJueSardH
    T4CLskqG/SUC9bXOZJYqntC0gWx2nk47WhPKp5xlpXt3RuPklWcM7y1Pj9qzY4fb
    Iw23bY0e555LTBpQjZWM0j44lC1Rx6BbaSGCHb3n3kySeZa8ytmA+Jf9M+UYoTHO
    ydEEAOIsjHpcILkW9oa6V/amTRDntpD1IWeWDKi41BWaVPelxkPJfn4cmlb6JQnS
    1/NqsXzCBKidMQSPs4hpexnEPOxOh8R3h3+UTNZHbWHcyfTtVu/ISjvKlI42rosV
    hwdN9pqdcZLOFC/rAgkyG4wLm3iI1ouOJuORG+q4PDhcxu0ZBAD9MdCFL9/CVin+
    W0V+/c8wkeaaliw6nBBk37ZR+nr5E/ayXos4jM920Cdq+Gn07z4zWaA3kjyUYWB8
    tvFDiwdvr8tW3Fg3RJOC/qzlmHtgyzepiUUDkE/9W6azbdmntPVTNKRaQEYl3+Uy
    Y8O7cypq5oiIoJqzYEHufgAUi+vJyQP/WKeJVZCtBD1hY6yOoV1n0yBvB9IU2Y9l
    +yq6bCI4E+YjMRp/3hpL9In3UkPkSSpR6g1i6qrPJ+obIVsTI9S7WDwGwt3sXfPz
    G+CT//3h8qZBf/LuqsI1FhvH66p9uK/0XD+XjNJf3oJB9qvpVvBABuH1HQKddWBA
    PTCUZ+nQtZRK37QeUFJPRklHQVRFIDxoYW1mcmlAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20+iQFOBBMB
    CgA4FiEEQ8t2sG16CAItmf8VQEnNax3vDvMFAl+xvukCGy8FCwkIBwIGFQoJCAsC
    BBYCAwECHgECF4AACgkQQEnNax3vDvMnqwgAhruKoBZEhL8qjp2xjI+iPHJkATbY
    EAD3otsUoZXgWiQExDVZUTnb9oQinuL7ut9blq4XGT/EXP2T8SSWXAtkyZ7JpJE1
    XfMatAkC6rg3BbJ2wJRP0WaacfsWi8zBKnJEBeycSsBQjcYHc635Q7/U5BvUXNfz
    fhg96z/J3X7HTloSG3m3aDu2uBeeljjJaML0fwUPEKWkuX0m8n25qPDuJWn3q5a9
    t3sxrNNYLvggMntq/azKh0ZpM3B9nsxQpHcL104HGn5trJZM6EI/y+8GVP0wPlBk
    kvcgdnlrXWgwYmee3LbKfD+06icvLY5lhia1/pub0RGADUrrvI5E6hOgFZ0DmARf
    sb7pAQgAmnm8e4mw5DZ6AsNABm1br+PJTRCOYFJDb92KX9soC8ZyXnF4++z+Iii9
    VBODDcRdDHGy6XAd8XADnUqqetdKZH2mxLh5fXshBOuZSWPBVbJA5805HbJNtxKJ
    u+ZscKCfHGAf9hK5AH95vvsJRuqTFihynrPK5118QWvffAARE38GP9NKuwSGD9uv
    3zrE9onYFPjM03x5tLXkmv8Nzo0wE8RLru26DPLHKuZgIDFsJRVrURkQ6tRHQ3tI
    +eLHnT8JUJuyeBdOrR2eE0FItcBUiuRuiUKfT0v9M6X8QyQTfsOlBju6IoHFRE/v
    GJpmkznWRFwad3ur4lhphU+XgdcLVwARAQABAAf/Qq4w47zEbEZttXqVzRBwpwSz
    NL5kTwTDkmq1m/oMl8SiQs1Fla2v54vhagUAKbWtGr2LpsOcUUdyb/e2jk8XkDhD
    ACDHZJh9YNPYN7tFTdojtUu7j2uTq2ZnqQHmpllXRVbjBQQA8suUAJH5Z7DDLCnq
    jEH84JFUnSLU9gBLXrfnB2kaq1bNwn34owudgKmNDuCoTRKOzfDwCvfHWjGsrv/5
    bLr8Aolo4M0pjhGLtTXclBQOr+abMPsmSU6bxFGImqRqiGq8Xrgj//Js82hzpeFr
    UZNPj5Bx4zqTnLh9krXrc+RXtqSyw70Fr5kPavtKmZK/Ugq2nZcaB0Qh8SVwWQQA
    xH+DdJd3AiHd5VqiH7jBBGoyt22oNUHNJ9tS356d/byk1M1M/znN3KULGXSiEcau
    SYkis6zxtLli7c89PaOETB+jxMBTglBvXfqBdLaVb7bcoyu9TGS4ZhiostxaGWHo
    pSvVsQnQ2+3aj8OuLfdmYDNT6i8v/fcI6U1kL6A5jfkEAMlApKnxUN239eF+dDw2
    dWY+YR52jIxePi0lde1QJ3ULrXGnTlRKpA84araTfzqr2cG6WLIrdBkJzgOFIaiN
    wUzrbKmzSHMEzYlM1nYZJ0qvIHcqjKqJiCcCn99PNvIpPU855vNo8g28DDvd0E71
    x1RzGudMF2w8lbaXoeoiYvfPA/9fqtkYsK3clTR99lBy0BLdWn2eZ4fj7jA3jAcA
    dK2o1gQri3dA47wiwyB+1kz/uj9Q6Eaz2C1R5XSKQn+28cOCHJ9mNvXwd4K/FEBy
    p/TN5PUJkDDGRJW7jIo32KB4WwPVMvzj6A+IaV/oDMIgN9zR2DprJIwR+mSlKcfr
    eZcg9EpAiQJsBBgBCgAgFiEEQ8t2sG16CAItmf8VQEnNax3vDvMFAl+xvukCGy4B
    QAkQQEnNax3vDvPAdCAEGQEKAB0WIQRgdT431gF+2C6i4ZNGvDeTCa5Q0gUCX7G+
    6QAKCRBGvDeTCa5Q0kzaB/9ZQ1sKCgf4vKfgnMSgrS7JzU6EgrJuW35A8lrpLuSL
    JFXpiy6r08HTCeHtC40941ELVa27wRQ3joCwnlKWklgTLRDq2/u+VGtnoJSQUSw1
    9+eav/aKiTPr661qstR+erikI8WEWmanWSl2nxrqYx22t0a9lR9S0LtVgmRL4Lp/
    cXAcnROXs+BkfvjuZZV7dOMIyxSzS0wTd+bcNklvxZiQ0rQetBqiZFTDbusytyp0
    +pTzmPTXv3pUnaw8rn4kN20/q2lL8igxkvj2+rNDB+HEJdyXsMi0qEF/W1kLwKCl
    O91sJmg+0h5MKFL2IHADVDkpBAj38ea8LFNRZ+NCMzb3gPcIAMS6saiX5DC/6GSr
    jFbqWY9QstPHDFW3+1BYV+Fs0W2UutZ0vmAzN8LO7mKVXNalemKM82osRCwFXSal
    uoX5o6GcqS08DGBJOaFiWxQ5cSSBEYNeq2/Esq6ejW4bIlWUYRmQx6/1dST2vgx3
    TH4gbNpVkrwNHijqUzuIr6qDnk+reYrNqq57WPuRJ86BEtW3dnVU4oPSLdC2reQW
    FALtFgSkf6YGF0bbZOFdk41/6NS6mB5/5ao11bICKvQlOXB9JihiSJOteKmAx8wv
    TXYRnrUxH039PaOpdAdzMf4OAFw1Hsd5qR4+ZDdAzeRlGitKPg+YxQ48iHDfFPrW
    hVub9BQ=
    =+jZf
    -----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
    ";
    
    $message = "Testing again and again";
    $gpg = new gnupg();
    $publicKey = $gpg->import($public_key1);
    $fingerprint = $publicKey['fingerprint'];
    // catch errors
    $gpg->seterrormode(gnupg::ERROR_EXCEPTION);
    // enable armored output 
    $gpg->setarmor(1);
    $gpg -> setsignmode(gnupg::SIG_MODE_DETACH);
    
    // encrypt plain text
    try{
        $gpg->addencryptKey($fingerprint);
        $cipher_text = $gpg->encrypt($plain_text);
        echo "\n". $cipher_text ."\n";
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        die('Error '.$e->getMessage());
    }
    
    /**
     * step #2 (Decryption)
     * decrypt message from hamfri@example.com in step 1
     */
    
    //public key for hamfri@example.com
    $publickey2 = "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
    
    mQENBF+xvukBCADfsgmVrgw95kpxL+yM0BRC4Z/UHRoOCj4N9lOyvhUoa9rs30/W
    Xd8RXddkF2pjPr2OjRRe+PbpKxkkxAe1qxmICaIh/Xp/gS6XHGdqgvX/PuQhw3+T
    eGSVdXLxSwRdlGW1AZeH3WWSmqviYEtkwxWoah6g4ubmd/b6wp3EtSw4YpA3l1+C
    J313MV1IbptjJkrLHy+JqAV4CA6ziCkOwERc5fvtNdmmvbXrMfb5ObN2F6RfYwZS
    yLSvJB7n4CDsvLwGbXRHP0we0+eXJLt902k0uTW27IZhHElatvnxXwjqA5mcVfIK
    W3ks3VHLx0PbjIhghAUg7Pg8HgPlPGVBS8mhABEBAAG0HlBST0ZJR0FURSA8aGFt
    ZnJpQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tPokBTgQTAQoAOBYhBEPLdrBteggCLZn/FUBJzWsd7w7z
    BQJfsb7pAhsvBQsJCAcCBhUKCQgLAgQWAgMBAh4BAheAAAoJEEBJzWsd7w7zJ6sI
    AIa7iqAWRIS/Ko6dsYyPojxyZAE22BAA96LbFKGV4FokBMQ1WVE52/aEIp7i+7rf
    W5auFxk/xFz9k/EkllwLZMmeyaSRNV3zGrQJAuq4NwWydsCUT9FmmnH7FovMwSpy
    RAXsnErAUI3GB3Ot+UO/1OQb1FzX834YPes/yd1+x05aEht5t2g7trgXnpY4yWjC
    9H8FDxClpLl9JvJ9uajw7iVp96uWvbd7MazTWC74IDJ7av2syodGaTNwfZ7MUKR3
    C9dOBxp+bayWTOhCP8vvBlT9MD5QZJL3IHZ5a11oMGJnnty2ynw/tOonLy2OZYYm
    tf6bm9ERgA1K67yOROoToBW5AQ0EX7G+6QEIAJp5vHuJsOQ2egLDQAZtW6/jyU0Q
    jmBSQ2/dil/bKAvGcl5xePvs/iIovVQTgw3EXQxxsulwHfFwA51KqnrXSmR9psS4
    eX17IQTrmUljwVWyQOfNOR2yTbcSibvmbHCgnxxgH/YSuQB/eb77CUbqkxYocp6z
    yuddfEFr33wAERN/Bj/TSrsEhg/br986xPaJ2BT4zNN8ebS15Jr/Dc6NMBPES67t
    ugzyxyrmYCAxbCUVa1EZEOrUR0N7SPnix50/CVCbsngXTq0dnhNBSLXAVIrkbolC
    n09L/TOl/EMkE37DpQY7uiKBxURP7xiaZpM51kRcGnd7q+JYaYVPl4HXC1cAEQEA
    AYkCbAQYAQoAIBYhBEPLdrBteggCLZn/FUBJzWsd7w7zBQJfsb7pAhsuAUAJEEBJ
    zWsd7w7zwHQgBBkBCgAdFiEEYHU+N9YBftguouGTRrw3kwmuUNIFAl+xvukACgkQ
    Rrw3kwmuUNJM2gf/WUNbCgoH+Lyn4JzEoK0uyc1OhIKyblt+QPJa6S7kiyRV6Ysu
    q9PB0wnh7QuNPeNRC1Wtu8EUN46AsJ5SlpJYEy0Q6tv7vlRrZ6CUkFEsNffnmr/2
    iokz6+utarLUfnq4pCPFhFpmp1kpdp8a6mMdtrdGvZUfUtC7VYJkS+C6f3FwHJ0T
    l7PgZH747mWVe3TjCMsUs0tME3fm3DZJb8WYkNK0HrQaomRUw27rMrcqdPqU85j0
    1796VJ2sPK5+JDdtP6tpS/IoMZL49vqzQwfhxCXcl7DItKhBf1tZC8CgpTvdbCZo
    PtIeTChS9iBwA1Q5KQQI9/HmvCxTUWfjQjM294D3CADEurGol+Qwv+hkq4xW6lmP
    ULLTxwxVt/tQWFfhbNFtlLrWdL5gMzfCzu5ilVzWpXpijPNqLEQsBV0mpbqF+aOh
    nKktPAxgSTmhYlsUOXEkgRGDXqtvxLKuno1uGyJVlGEZkMev9XUk9r4Md0x+IGza
    VZK8DR4o6lM7iK+qg55Pq3mKzaque1j7kSfOgRLVt3Z1VOKD0i3Qtq3kFhQC7RYE
    pH+mBhdG22ThXZONf+jUupgef+WqNdWyAir0JTlwfSYoYkiTrXipgMfML012EZ61
    MR9N/T2jqXQHczH+DgBcNR7HeakePmQ3QM3kZRorSj4PmMUOPIhw3xT61oVbm/QU
    =9rM9
    -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
    ";
    
    //private key for hamfri-2@example.com
    $privateKey2 = "-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
    
    lQOYBF+xv34BCAD9ttzdbXx81yKIlWi0zqRgHVYc07M9ymoqCzoIIrmaCcvkARAJ
    I4IZ36PnXxnLdfMehMDjxeT6PAJDb71oMc85jA+h5c+ya4b+m9OwlGW/e7WgieBB
    WGt8NRnnKjwGbwDq7qd2aC2T/ZDBZQFF4wAJjoZop5Wh7NxK8QFV05ES6KXU/hJF
    wySbyoSYJb4A3VNrpoEF92vA22aUFn2RrktCXwaaMXoOyLuFDebxOrKgzI5EfhMa
    CRBxv4ufNfcAm1uEpqILngou/kxUs5QYW6VaSmV858+bpzcMGR73X1hHY9p0dHO1
    QTaIJU/8E91whaCxihDOsyO5jJG6DIhEbwJVABEBAAEAB/0aVKuIWXAFfshJN4RV
    22pIxVKmDDx6abLp6R9dL8lmWKTt5URWRnaem8ylWwPQz01reeiQ2v1gEPFFMWgN
    U7oHZWdL7I9JG4q3itGF7mi+3iZj4ltBPN1u1w34pTP0kPmd6CW+DqLITJUE1Sg0
    KhJba4y8eMP5OZ1FM8zpLNtOBF0nW6D0q0/QZKRRtivTrJDrERgsfSwFAbXvxdig
    eQtXcP4BWtR7c0Xx+aHIjEkE7etgTt7BZmoe5dkotHeV4fVFH8GzBrnN8FvAAsNe
    vQgE6uTGGHFsIRfCX4GF9SYMcmHCCUVi9re/5GSaGb26Bl348QwHh1Yf3SqULKu7
    abUhBAD+W9512kxJSCSj5nhliIN6ce8+bvM7n34dlTG0HqBE2/ygfXllVapyHZbP
    ubbY4sFSlrv8ROJcu4ieAfa/ho+adKnjYUiiKhbVD3umJsfSTosyTRhsSWldGRyc
    3v16IQrudVFB300dn0CPi57+sXPNZprGjI+NqpnD1+hDAW/5sQQA/1nt3A5CukqA
    3u44LLiMQt35wj0VmHogcbiv0Gteur8fvh4K6UI1NnGWTWQdSExSGGvmXtzvne0O
    Lp1Howj/C5pYqk+bs/yeFQAhzWenZ9pGJYFnG+/HLjk/eK/aXjZKPCuWd11RPsUr
    RKVJ1jE+Rt6ltRfWjXzv0GlBYzzh1+UD/i/FYhpz9Md791G7eeswoewuMCAUlzfe
    FlmuB/deyr6PDlvvK3Q5fZHRCrzH/RvycKu671j84QX2hiofnib/sBAo6xDvFq1h
    ecEFxC7pxeBgRJJUe3fPmtu/PAWvpJEYuF8lr8+n9oEHEbsMPctckweUaAAc/act
    kwoBMJhhWFS8QLO0IFBST0ZJR0FURSA8aGFtZnJpLTJAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20+iQFO
    BBMBCgA4FiEEFL28kQaiGEUK7cm+n15EvbMdHkgFAl+xv34CGy8FCwkIBwIGFQoJ
    CAsCBBYCAwECHgECF4AACgkQn15EvbMdHkhFIggAsvxVIZOTo9SrNvEERUz05X8z
    7+CNR1m4rCL4Q5mtaFhL0RcsH2FpLqd7+96JtxFBRL5XaUiDQeVc1qzSNnr062Dt
    R0jxvR59Rg+aBfyX2haNHKbD3Dw6e2WaDXMeOkhJjS2h16Wc+4ztRerGQ0vI+fTa
    Imrs43uCuzKrMPo39/hxewv5BXRpkXrSCZ/X9jTH+XQxBsEaXe+W9pW5tXpSSVUk
    ccBwuKWJBygzI41PQ+Xi39tn+TxVk+kFDASV7uvYMPU3IBdbQ/F8xcnb6q6uH2r7
    lIZRUSsj/H3SHlcDwiBXZgez49Re9eZjFpvp7lUiXQeGMktj3MboVAHglOw6sp0D
    mARfsb9+AQgAxVvq+VApWsPaN7Wgj1uepVtunJ8BiEZ2CNq6mM32rTfYrw3Ckv7l
    fKHNsTVo7Ek8bWbxR1I/DhBCvDDRijtEWkNFGO1EfQx+2mYJPsPiO9Y+HoL7L839
    FapXqrPLnhEczR3s8IkTZrggZ2ClZ2pI8cwSGysW4wxjExzoEiXyoF4XVZZWJgq2
    blkXP5avnZhmWyK88e0ZFmut1+dO/eJ3nFT9uxqBXZSlLVuo4GGVLz+Xa3ZuJKtA
    CEyNQnJ4zYVrW/zLyVSThN5Um95QB2A0hup1f92oMs5jiUAk/PFPs3h6qOqIsTo5
    gyuXM/c39ZqGM474c2yY0ImpolXqZ85rNwARAQABAAf+LCbfnu3pioY1O/BUnq2z
    BLA7QyupVpjY0CtKwmOVc3QCdEsiQ+tlYKf8EdBujCnoLFtyz+9c7uMBYwOS5RdU
    N9ND0otGHqmceXSJTfLZmmRYGlBYLH4rR90HZsd5Xn/ajyLKPpeT8Q9xJF9xMX0M
    G5f5Vv2hTaMYSQ7W9jRqHqj5H/CFC4Rq4oGkOmqoeA5njSVZ660riiX2CEbVudrN
    /nlHrYV3sH/wQIKMWyAOjVnClcGFho1G1QdWgj0v7dYEjcnIqiSBBaOL01GdCCuw
    QBRY7TehU/Eqo+sQ4GJ17qz32di1wI+59Q5PNKuMX18pO5iH/4IyyXFeO1tGA6rb
    wQQAzf7YbnYcLSoM5ShHeemxEGQaKJ0COnz4XpqEhyDP6T0nUa4DK3YExFoNHOH8
    2DmcE7PeWpLCXMHdsmVCloKcHXSTVQUspbuoBVGFcnbym2hCyQngQwXi5XekRpMH
    8KstXCicicfn8wnPXRmYfJYysLXivWHPn2i1MkLSF+603cEEAPVEYR6BI0TrEHVi
    MQxlTnloyG17LlV5miOTPg+SQvfzppE560CaYi3fI9KndU4jWqbz25eQFG2VryUC
    b58NE0FsRfMfYppHGAZXjGl9PmLCihPjYU310GRbPulhQQJ4io/nJajpqYjoNqxU
    zD6ihiBd2tKt6L+d8By9S9Yxdfb3BACjDKrdBrMj/BwhNvNt74e4Db79sj8rrFpv
    KfoDmuwdLVEUSjQnojRy4+qVQ3cpPrpjb3NIjV/RKpMYbvkRTRm/91n4NuCWBIA5
    v4EbQl17msB4FMTBhXaNgGT4Z49rJG/BeWzdqRJeIGkIUBSwlMpTSZbjmpMaWfK0
    T4YdSMzB6jXCiQJsBBgBCgAgFiEEFL28kQaiGEUK7cm+n15EvbMdHkgFAl+xv34C
    Gy4BQAkQn15EvbMdHkjAdCAEGQEKAB0WIQR3zuJGs/Iyh6FlFq91FMPrcW4x3gUC
    X7G/fgAKCRB1FMPrcW4x3ozOB/45X6+t9JeUSBp1e1jfr+CJMAlf6HiSsQd7BpA1
    UFGU42oOBqFNpT7q7TwcUlbf9JHq8qL10SuPgIot04vDQSsaMxWc8X/E4OCDo9Wh
    OT5CwmjJLzmQwhWzpAlhw93sQTJY7oKyW3lasxyDjBhIDHz0lagNfU6S5ZkR8U5S
    2qoM6VRrbDVP224HXXjhLUvbChF+G5MvWaAOExPvz2Sc69jcQaQ5D4PM65qfatoJ
    ZEdQjREnYGU4c7ZqPPunQSbIlMzufFsu2mMM1/mLKMA12+VPoMbrzoMoJD4ENNsF
    jXmYjlDlwLrs1pYDu7bjm5Aqz1iylMrup+eiv5TqXFX93PR50+UH/A0gg6LkuBJO
    J9G1TCN/G32NmB3/NOhLPZgdF9E36cxV6/EiOwYP2YVG4eBS+Sajk4PieYupNI91
    rwU5O9gRUCekv3TbI7F41oin/tF9++RoLpGyRjOT4P7PsBfg9PTIzHBlVmIBo88J
    P14IhRcNnajX81Mw01esspl2+bkX1MgmZ7SPoODZ422BLYEt8qQrxLoOI6gUzz/N
    pY4OpoRSQdx3TEmHKzLIIWZgkMC1IwNX4Jc4gLF8pMD4miSwm5RRlHzop7APmCs6
    F7jC+evoH3xWQTvkq7Rrh0ykvZOeX+kEvEfglFrFDM2GE0XVy+khDenC6BHgx2D6
    ZJIPOs18pko=
    =1CCf
    -----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
    ";
    
    
    $encryptedPrivateKey=OpenPGP_Message::parse(OpenPGP::unarmor($privateKey2,'PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK'));
    
    // Try each secret key packet
    foreach($encryptedPrivateKey as $p) {
        if(!($p instanceof OpenPGP_SecretKeyPacket)) continue;
    
        $key2 = new OpenPGP_SecretKeyPacket($p->key);
    
        $msg = OpenPGP_Message::parse(OpenPGP::unarmor($cipher_text, 'PGP MESSAGE'));
    
        $decryptor = new OpenPGP_Crypt_RSA($key2);
        $decrypted = $decryptor->decrypt($msg);
        var_dump($decrypted);
    }
```

Comment: Hopefully that's a test key and not your REAL private key.  If it is not a test key, I would recommend you revoke it and generate a new one, and then don't ever publish the secret key.

Comment: All the keys used are dummy keys meant for this question specifically.